# Own beforeSave handler for the apostrophe widget

Tags: apostrophe-cms

How to code the *beforeSave()* handler for the apostrophe widget? This code in the widget index.js does not work for me:

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'My widget',
  addFields: [
  {
      name: 'label',
      type: 'string',
      label: 'Caption',
      required: true
  }
  ],
  construct: function(self, options) {

    self.beforeSave = function(callback) {
      console.log("beforeSave");
      return callback();
    }
  }
};
```

When I save an instance of a widget, the log does not change. Is it possible to code your own *beforeSave()* handler for widgets as for pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A widget is just one part of a document, and documents are saved to the database as a unit, not individual widgets. So there is no `beforeSave`.

However if what you want to do is take some action each time a widget is sanitized for potential inclusion in a document that may be saved, take a look at the `sanitize` method:

```
self.sanitize = function(req, input, callback) {
  var output = self.apos.schemas.newInstance(self.schema);
  var schema = self.allowedSchema(req);
  output._id = self.apos.launder.id(input._id) || self.apos.utils.generateId();
  return self.apos.schemas.convert(req, schema, 'form', input, output, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    output.type = self.name;
    return callback(null, output);
  });
};
```

Notice how this method takes `input`, which is the data the browser provided, and runs it through `apos.schemas.convert` to copy only the valid data to `output`. Then it sends `output` to its callback.

We can use the "super pattern" to make a change at the end of this process. For instance, rich text widgets usually don't have a schema, they just have a `content` property containing markup. But, they might have a schema too on some sites. So here is how the `apostrophe-rich-text-widgets` module uses the "super pattern" to extend the `sanitize` method to accept the additional content, without losing the ability to save schema content:

```
var superSanitize = self.sanitize;
self.sanitize = function(req, input, callback) {
  return superSanitize(req, input, function(err, output) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    output.content = sanitizeHtml(input.content, self.options.sanitizeHtml);
    return callback(null, output);
  });
};
```

Notice that:

- The original version of the method is captured in the variable `superSanitize`. Then a new function is assigned as the method.
- The original version of `superSanitize` is called. If it fails we deal with that first.
- `output` is modified. Any changes you make to `output` will go directly into the widget in the document, so make sure you validate any content you are accepting from `input`. Browsers (and scripts written by hackers) can lie.
- We end the same way the original method does: by invoking the callback with `(null, output)`.